# Creating new Dataframe data slicing issue

Tags: python, pandas, finance

This is my code snippet. The code works however, I am getting the following error:

"A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"

I am guessing this is due to some deprecated syntax...

```
new_data['mon_fri'] = 0
for i in range(0,len(new_data)):
    if (new_data['Dayofweek'][i] == 0 or new_data['Dayofweek'][i] == 4):
        new_data['mon_fri'][i] = 1
    else:
        new_data['mon_fri'][i] = 0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2):

Dont loop in pandas if exist vectorized alternatives, here is possible use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for boolean mask and cast to integer for `True/False` to `1/0` mapping:

```
new_data['mon_fri'] = new_data['Dayofweek'].isin([0,4]).astype(int)
```

Or use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
new_data['mon_fri'] = np.where(new_data['Dayofweek'].isin([0,4]), 1, 0)
```